# kotlin: syntax for 2 lambda parameter

Tags: java, lambda, syntax, kotlin, kotlin-interop

I'm new to kotlin. I have a java class with 2 overloaded methods. One accepts one function, the other one accepts two

```
mapToEntry(Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper)
```

and

```
mapToEntry(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper, 
           Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper)
```

nowm in kotlin, i'm trying to call the the version with 2 parameters (as in java):

```
myClass.mapToEntry(r -> r, r -> r)
```

but i get compilation error.

> Kotlin: Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)

what's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Kotlin, lambda expressions are always surrounded by curly braces, so it's

```
myClass.mapToEntry({ r -> r }, { r -> r })
```

See: [Lambda Expression Syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax)

Answer (score 5):

You were close, you just have to wrap them in curly braces...

```
myClass.mapToEntry({r -> r}, {r -> r})
```

Also, you can take advantage of the fact that Kotlin defines `it` as the default single parameter to a lambda. Assuming the key and value are both Strings, and you want to reverse the key and uppercase the value (just making up an example):

```
myClass.mapToEntry( { it.reversed() }, { it.toUpperCase() })
```

Answer (score 4):

**Basic Syntax**: Lambda expressions are always wrapped in curly braces:

```
val sum = { x: Int, y: Int -> x + y }
```

#### Example

Let's define a function similar to yours in Kotlin:

```
fun <T, K> mapToEntry(f1: (T) -> K, f2: (T) -> K) {}
```

The **first** possibily is straight forward, we simply pass two lambdas as follows:

```
mapToEntry<String, Int>({ it.length }, { it.length / 2 })
```

Additionally, it's good to know that if a lambda is the last argument passed to a function, it can be lifted out the parantheses like so:

```
mapToEntry<String, Int>({ it.length }) {
    it.length / 2
}
```

The first lambda is passed inside the parantheses, whereas the second isn't.